# Comparing values of 2 tables and highlighting the rows that are different

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need to compare values from two tables that are identical but contain some different data. I must find and highlight that diff. How can I do that?

```
<table class="TableA">
  <tr> 
    <td>Head1</td>
    <td>Some_Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Head2</td>
    <td>SomeValue</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="TableB">
  <tr>
    <td>Head1</td>
    <td>Some_Value</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>Head2</td>
    <td>SomeValueDiffValue</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to compare this two tables and highlight diff in value cells with jquery, in above example I need to highlight SomeValueButDiff in second table

Ok, I modified Ahmet's code into this:

```
$(".TableB tr").each(function () {
if ($(this).find("td")[1].innerHTML !=
    $(".TableA").find("td")[1].innerHTML) {
    $(this).find("td")[1].bgColor = "red";
}
```

});

This works for me, thx Ahmet.

Comment: Your question is quite vague. It would help if you showed some code and pointed out where you are struggling.

Comment: Are you rendering the tables yourself or do you get the final HTML for comparison? If you are rendering it yourself, you would probably be better of doing the comparison on the server side.

Comment: I'm using two asp.net DetailsView controls with two diferent objects for source control and i get the output in tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit code if you have multi data cells in a row.

```
$(".TableA tr").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("td")[0].innerHTML != $(this).find("td")[1].innerHTML) {
        $(this).find("td")[0].bgColor = "red";
    }

});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7akB/)

Comment: I need to compare values from tableA with values in TableB